# How to use Github GraphQL search to return user profiles with similar name( including login and display name)?

Tags: github-api, github-graphql

I have this simple search query

```graphql
query test($name: String!) {
  search(query: $name, type: USER, last: 100) {
    edges {
      textMatches {
        fragment
        property
        highlights {
          text
        }
      }
    }
    userCount
  }
}
```

and say, for example, I would like to have the login information for all users from the search result. How would I do that? The results contain login or display names that matches the search text. Is there a way to find the login for those who only appear in the search because of their display name?

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there! In "edges", you're dealing with an array of [SearchResultItemEdge](https://developer.github.com/v4/reference/object/searchresultitemedge/) which contains a "node" property at the same level as "textMatches".

Since the node is a [SearchResultItem](https://developer.github.com/v4/reference/union/searchresultitem/), and can be one of User, Issue, PullRequest, etc, you have to specifically spread your node as a "User" in order to be able to access the login.

Give this query a try in the Explorer:

```
query test($name: String!) {
  search(query: $name, type: USER, last: 100) {
    edges {
      node {
        __typename
        ...on User {
          login
        }
      }
      textMatches {
        fragment
        property
        highlights {
          text
        }

      }
    }
    userCount
  }
}
```